# Removing factor levels from variable X based on values in Y

Tags: r

I have a larger data frame with many factor levels. I would like to remove those levels for which all corresponding Y values are zero.

An example data set:

```
df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), Y = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), .Names = c("X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

For this example, I would like to have the rows containing `B` and `E` removed.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(X) %>% filter(any(Y>0))` or ` df %>% group_by(X) %>% filter(!all(Y==0))`

Comment: You shared data reproducibly which is good, but to avoid downvotes in the future I'd suggest also showing what you tried.

Comment: @Gregor I tried a lot of things but I couldn't get it working for the condition that all Y values for the corresponding factor levels have to be zero in order for the rows to be excluded. Hence, I didn't add all my failed attempts. Will do it in the future though.

Comment: It often means instead of typing up a full answer, someone can just point out where you went wrong - and it clearly demonstrates that you're putting more effort in than just asking someone here to write code for you.

Comment: @Gregor I totally understand where you are coming from and will do it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'X' and `filter` for rows that have `any` value in 'Y' not equal to 0

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(X) %>%
    filter(any(Y != 0))
```

---

Or use the `all` with negate (`!`)

```
df %>% 
   group_by(X) %>% 
   filter(!all(Y==0))
```

Comment: @Stefan Note that this only removes the *values* of factor `X`, not the *levels* of that factor. To do that you will need `droplevels` or something to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in base R

```
df[df$X%in%df$X[df$Y!=0],]
   X Y
1  A 1
2  A 2
3  A 0
4  A 2
9  C 2
10 C 5
11 C 1
12 C 1
13 D 0
14 D 0
15 D 1
16 D 8
```